# Custom Walker: how to get ID in function start_lvl

Tags: customization, id, walker

I am making my first custom walker to build an accordion menu. To start with I used this example: http://bitacre.com/2025/custom-nav-menu-walker-for-wordpress-themes

There are two functions. First start_lvl and then start_el.

In start_el the ID get's implemented by $item->ID. Does anybody know how I can do this in start_lvl as well? I need to give the  (surrounding lower level navigation) an ID so I can trigger it to collapse in the accordion menu.

What I'm trying to generate is something like this:

```
<a href="#collapse2">Titel 2</a>
<ul id="collapse2">Lower Level Menu 2</ul>
<a href="#collapse3">Titel 3</a>
<ul id="collapse3">Lower Level Menu  3</ul>
```

My code for the start_lvl function:

```
// add id's and classes to ul sub-menus
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth, $item ) {
    // depth dependent classes
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
    $pgid = ; // How to get ID in here??
    $classes = array(
        'sub-menu',
        ( $display_depth == 1  ? 'accordion-body collapse' : '' ),
        ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
        ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
        'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
        );
    $ids = array(
        'collapse' . $pgid
        );
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );
    $id_name = implode( ' ', $ids );

    // build html
    $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul id="' . $id_name . '" class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 51):

I just had to do this in one of my themes... Since you don't have access to the $item variable at that stage of the Walker, you would want to store your current item in a more global scope at the moment you do have access to it. The following code will make more sense... note: I've stripped everything but the relevant code.

```
class ThemeTruck_Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
   private $curItem;

  // retrieve the curItem
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    var_dump($this->curItem );
  }

  // store the curItem
  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
    $this->curItem = $item;
  }

 }
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution presented in this thread. Thanks Lane!

Comment: Indeed a very clean approach that works well. Many thanks.

Comment: Im not sure but do i have to add the whole default code to start_el to make it work?

Comment: Ok you can just use parent::start_el($output,$item,$depth,$args,$id); in the start_el ...

Comment: Brilliant, been meaning to figure this out for ages and this worked right away. Thank you.

Comment: Nice!! I have really big menu to build and Your solution is like booom. Thank You!

Comment: Years later this has saved me! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following filter in your `start_el` function and grub your argument in `start_lvl` function.

```
apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_lvl', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args->myarg=$item->title );
```

Please let me know know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for posting! I hope to find some time to work it out in the next few days but I am really busy with my study just now. I will get back to you with the result!

Comment: Not sure if this filter used to exist, but there's no such filter in WP 5.5 that I can see

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add $page to the argument of the custom walker:

```
class My_Custom_Walker extends Walker_page {
    function start_el(&$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page) {
        if ( $depth )
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        else
            $indent = '';

        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

        $output .= $indent . 
            '<li>
            <a style="color:red" href="' . get_page_link($page->ID) . '" title="' . 
            esc_attr( wp_strip_all_tags( apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) ) ) . '">' . 
            $link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . $link_after . '</a>';
```

Try the above and then before you call wp_list_pages(), add the custom walker class:

```
$MyWalker = new My_Custom_Walker();
```

Then, in the arguments for wp_list_pages:

> wp_list_pages('walker' => $MyWalker)

Check and see if the output of the walker is red.

Comment: That is in function start_el, but it's apparently different in start_lvl because I can't put the same variables in there. Or at least not the same order.

Comment: What are you trying to do with start_lvl?

Comment: I am trying to give the <ul> an id="collapse102" with 102 the generated page ID. This way I can trigger it to collapse it in my accordion menu.

Comment: Adding the id="collapse" works, but I can't get it to work to add the pageID as well.

Comment: Do you mean that you want only specific IDs to be collapsed? I have an accordion tree for wp_list_pages and I don't need to alter start_lvl at all.

Comment: I've added an example of wat I am trying to generate

Comment: It's for wp_nav_menu don't know that makes any difference for wp_list_pages

Comment: Hi AlxVallejo, I can't get it to work the way I thought I could so i have to change my approach. How did you make your accordion for wp_list_pages?

Comment: @RobertBouten I updated my answer. I'm actually using a plugin called list-pages-shortcode so that I don't have to call the class on every page template. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @RobertBouten I realize this doesn't get you 100% to the accordion, which will depend on the jQuery you use. You would most likely give each link a class to be called on from the jQuery DOM. I'd be happy to walk you through how I did it.

Comment: Thnx Alx, I will start working on it and get back to you if I have any more questions.