# How to add odd and even classes to all nav links through walker?

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I kept finding posts that explain how to add even and odd classes to sub-menu items, but can't seem to find how to add it to the main menu items that do not have sub menus.

I've already checked out the following links:

- http://shinraholdings.com/62/custom-nav-menu-walker-function/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/applying-evenodd-classes/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#comment-207
- [Customizing a walker menu class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105504/customizing-a-walker-menu-class/#answer-105521)
- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/odd-class-to-odd-lis-within-sub-menu-uls
- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-page-id-to-walker-function-start_lvl
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354343/add-odd-class-to-odd-lis-within-sub-menu-uls-using-custom-walker
- [Custom Walker: how to get ID in function start_lvl](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62054/custom-walker-how-to-get-id-in-function-start-lvl)
- [Custom nav walker with different output depending on depth](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204872/custom-nav-walker-with-different-output-depending-on-depth)
- [Customizing a walker menu class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105504/customizing-a-walker-menu-class)

Here's my class:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

class detailed_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

  // Add First & Last Classes To Navigational Menu Objects
  static function first_last_menu_class( $objects, $args ) {

    // Add first/last classes to nested menu items
    $ids        = array();
    $parent_ids = array();
    $top_ids    = array();
    foreach ( $objects as $i => $object ) {
      // If there is no menu item parent, store the ID and skip over the object
      if ( 0 == $object->menu_item_parent ) {
        $top_ids[$i] = $object;
        continue;
      }

      // Add first item class to nested menus
      if ( ! in_array( $object->menu_item_parent, $ids ) ) {
        $objects[$i]->classes[] = 'first-menu-item';
        $ids[] = $object->menu_item_parent;
      }

      // If we have just added the first menu item class, skip over adding the ID
      if ( in_array( 'first-menu-item', $object->classes ) )
        continue;

      // Store the menu parent IDs in an array
      $parent_ids[$i] = $object->menu_item_parent;
    }

    // Remove any duplicate values and pull out the last menu item
    $sanitized_parent_ids = array_unique( array_reverse( $parent_ids, true ) );

    // Loop through the IDs and add the last menu item class to the appropriate objects
    foreach ( $sanitized_parent_ids as $i => $id )
      $objects[$i]->classes[] = 'last-menu-item';

    // Finish it off by adding classes to the top level menu items
    $objects[1]->classes[] = 'first-menu-item'; // We can be assured 1 will be the first item in the menu :-)
    $objects[array_keys( $top_ids )[count( array_keys( $top_ids ) ) - 1]]->classes[] = 'last-menu-item';

    // Return the menu objects
    return $objects;

  }

  // add classes to ul sub-menus
  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    // depth dependent classes
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth + 1 ); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
    $classes = array(
      'sub-menu toggleable',
      ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
      ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
      'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
    );
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

    // build html
    $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
  }

  // add main/sub classes to li's and links
  function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

    // depth dependent classes
    $depth_classes = array(
      ( $depth == 0 ? 'main-menu-item' : 'sub-menu-item' ),
      ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ),
      ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
      'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
    );
    $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

    // passed classes
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

    // build html
    $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

    // link attributes
    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ' class="menu-link ' . ( $depth > 0 ? 'sub-menu-link' : 'main-menu-link' ) . '"';

    if ( $item->hasChildren ) {
      $args->after = sprintf( '<input type="checkbox" id="%1$s-%2$s-checkbox" hidden><label class="toggler" for="%1$s-%2$s-checkbox" onclick><i class="fa fa-lg fa-caret-down"></i></label>', $item->ID, $args->theme_location );
    } else {
      $args->after = null;
    }

    $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
      $args->before,
      $attributes,
      $args->link_before,
      apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
      $args->link_after,
      $args->after
    );

    // build html
    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args, $id );
  }
  function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output ) {
    // check, whether there are children for the given ID and append it to the element with a (new) ID
    $element->hasChildren = isset( $children_elements[$element->ID] ) && !empty( $children_elements[$element->ID] );

    return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: may be an obvious answer, but why you don't introduce the classes through the WP menu ui?

Comment: @Capiedge Great suggestion, thank you. I'd still like to be able to automate it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out the [walk method from the original Walker class source at WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker/walk/) and used that to get my result. I added a couple of more things to it, including:

- Adding `first` and `last` classes to the every `ul` in the navigational menu.
- Adding `odd` and `even` classes to every `li` relative to the position it is in its `ul`.
- Adding `before-parent` and `after-parent` classes to every `li` that precedes or follows a parent, even if the element itself is a parent.

Here's the code(just add this to your walker class):

```
/**
 * Traverse elements to create list from elements.
 *
 * Display one element if the element doesn't have any children otherwise,
 * display the element and its children. Will only traverse up to the max
 * depth and no ignore elements under that depth. It is possible to set the
 * max depth to include all depths, see walk() method.
 */
public function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output) {
  $element->is_subitem = ((!empty($children_elements[$element->ID]) && (($depth + 1) < $max_depth || ($max_depth === 0))));

  if ($element->is_subitem) {
    foreach ($children_elements[$element->ID] as $child) {
      if ($child->current_item_parent || $this->url_compare($this->archive, $child->url)) {
        $element->classes[] = 'active';
      }
    }
  }

  $element->is_active = (!empty($element->url) && strpos($this->archive, $element->url));

  if ($element->is_active) {
    $element->classes[] = 'active';
  }

  parent::display_element($element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output);
}

/*
 * Display array of elements hierarchically.
 * Does not assume any existing order of elements.
 * $max_depth = -1 means flatly display every element.
 * $max_depth = 0 means display all levels.
 * $max_depth > 0 specifies the number of display levels.
 */
public function walk( $elements, $max_depth ) {
  $args = array_slice( func_get_args(), 2 );
  $output = '';

  // Invalid parameter or nothing to walk.
  if ( $max_depth < -1 || empty( $elements ) ) {
    return $output;
  }

  $parent_field = $this->db_fields['parent'];

  // Flat display.
  if ( -1 == $max_depth ) {
    $empty_array = array();
    foreach ( $elements as $e )
      $this->display_element( $e, $empty_array, 1, 0, $args, $output );
    return $output;
  }

  /*
   * Need to display in hierarchical order.
   * Separate elements into two buckets: top level and children elements.
   * Children_elements is two dimensional array, eg.
   * Children_elements[10][] contains all sub-elements whose parent is 10.
   */
  $top_level_elements = array();
  $children_elements  = array();
  foreach ( $elements as $e ) {
    if ( empty( $e->$parent_field ) )
      $top_level_elements[] = $e;
    else
      $children_elements[ $e->$parent_field ][] = $e;
  }

  /*
   * When none of the elements is top level.
   * Assume the first one must be root of the sub elements.
   */
  if ( empty( $top_level_elements ) ) {

    $first = array_slice( $elements, 0, 1 );
    $root = $first[0];

    $top_level_elements = array();
    $children_elements  = array();
    foreach ( $elements as $e ) {
      if ( $root->$parent_field == $e->$parent_field )
        $top_level_elements[] = $e;
      else
        $children_elements[ $e->$parent_field ][] = $e;
    }
  }

  /*
   * Add number of positions per hierarchy using arrays from earlier at the top of the function.
   * One for top level elements and the other for child elements.
   */
  foreach ( $top_level_elements as $i => $e ) {                                     // Loop to add classes to top level elements loop.
    array_push( $e->classes, ( $i+1 ) % 2  ? 'odd' : 'even' );                      // Add odd and even classes based on position.

    // Add [before | after]-parent classes to element.
    if ($i <> count( $top_level_elements ) - 1 ) {                                  // If it is not the last element.
      if (array_key_exists($top_level_elements[$i + 1 ]->ID, $children_elements)) { // If next element is a parent.
        array_push($e->classes, 'before-parent');                                   // Add before-parent class.
      }
    }
    if ($i <> 0) {                                                                  // If it is not the first element.
      if (array_key_exists($top_level_elements[$i - 1 ]->ID, $children_elements)) { // If previous element is a parent.
        array_push($e->classes, 'after-parent');                                    // Add after-parent class.
      }
    }

    // Add first and last classes to items.
    if ( $i == 0 ) {
      array_push( $e->classes, 'first' );                                           // Add first class to first item.
    } elseif ( $i == ( count( $top_level_elements ) - 1 ) ) {
      array_push( $e->classes, 'last' );                                            // Add last class to last item.
    }
  }

  foreach ( $children_elements as $children ) {                                     // Loop to add classes to child level elements loop.
    foreach ( $children as $i => $e ) {
      array_push( $e->classes, ( $i+1 ) % 2  ? 'odd' : 'even' );                    // Add odd and even classes based on position.

      // Add [before | after]-parent classes to element.
      if ($i <> count( $children ) - 1 ) {                                          // If it is not the last element.
        if (array_key_exists($children[$i + 1 ]->ID, $children_elements)) {         // If next element is a parent.
          array_push($e->classes, 'before-parent');                                 // Add before-parent class.
        }
      }
      if ($i <> 0) {                                                                // If it is not the first element.
        if (array_key_exists($children[$i - 1 ]->ID, $children_elements)) {         // If previous element is a parent.
          array_push($e->classes, 'after-parent');                                  // Add after-parent class.
        }
      }

      if ( $i == 0 ) {
        array_push( $e->classes, 'first' );                                         // Add first class to first item.
      }if ( $i == ( count( $children ) - 1 ) ) {
        array_push( $e->classes, 'last' );                                          // Add last class to last item.
      }
    }
  }

  foreach ( $top_level_elements as $e )
    $this->display_element( $e, $children_elements, $max_depth, 0, $args, $output );

  /*
   * If we are displaying all levels, and remaining children_elements is not empty,
   * then we got orphans, which should be displayed regardless.
   */
  if ( ( $max_depth == 0 ) && count( $children_elements ) > 0 ) {
    $empty_array = array();
    foreach ( $children_elements as $orphans )
      foreach ( $orphans as $op )
        $this->display_element( $op, $empty_array, 1, 0, $args, $output );
  }

  return $output;
}
```

I also shared my entire [detailed navigational menu walker](https://gist.github.com/yaharga/443b97a1889a0ab20c2c29b276cdcd10) on Github if you wish to use it.